# Remove Duplicate Records in Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, distinct

I want to create a table that indicates medical providers that are linked by common members. For example, if I go to prov 1 and prov 2, then prov 1 and prov 2 will be linked because I visited both.

I have a table where each record indicates a member visiting a provider on a specific date. The table contains millions of members and thousands of provs. Below is a small example of the table:

```
member    prov    date
  1        1      1/1/15
  1        2      1/2/15
  2        16     1/12/14
  2        5      1/1/16
```

I am trying to create a table where each record indicates two distinct providers being linked by a common member. For example:

```
member    prov1    prov2    date1    date2
  1         1        2      1/1/15   1/2/15
  2        16        5      1/12/14  1/1/16
```

I am trying to use an inner join on the same table, but it is returning duplicate records. I thought the distinct clause would fix this, but it does not seem to get the job done.  My query is shown below:

```
select distinct a.member, a.prov, b.prov, a.date, b.date
from table1 as a
inner join table1 as b
on a.member=b.member
```

This query returns distinct records, but there are records that contain the same information.  Below shows an example of this:

```
a.member    a.prov    b.prov    a.date    b.date
   1          1         2       1/1/15    1/2/15
   1          2         1       1/2/15    1/1/15
```

Above we see that the records are distinct, but they describe the same information. Below is what I want the query to return:

```
a.member    a.prov    b.prov    a.date    b.date
   1          1         2       1/1/15    1/2/15
```

How can I alter the above query so that I only return distinct information? I don't want 1 record per member. I want 1 record for each distinct prov pairings by member.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `conditional aggregation` with a subquery using `row_number`:

```
select member,
       max(case when rn = 1 then prov end) prov1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then prov end) prov2,
       max(case when rn = 1 then date end) date1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then date end) date2
from (select member, 
             prov, 
             date, 
             row_number() over (partition by member order by prov, date) rn 
      from table1) t
group by member
```

Comment: That would work, but I will be using a table with hundreds of millions of rows. It won't be practical to do this for all records.

Comment: @RyanCaldwell -- If I'm not mistaken, what you are attempting to do is called table `pivoting`.  Are you expecting a dynamic list of columns?  If so, you'll have to use `dynamic sql`.  This is probably the most efficient approach though if you know there will not be more than 2 `prov`s per `member`...

Comment: There could be many different provs per member. There will be thousands of different distinct provs and millions of distinct members.

Comment: @RyanCaldwell -- This query will return 1 row per member, but only the first 2 `provs/dates` for each.  As I mentioned earlier, if you do not know how many columns you want to return (1 prov or 100 provs for example), you'll have to use `dynamic sql`.  I'm not sure how that's handled in `hive`, but you should be able to search for it...